# Magento site still not updating after changes to files

Tags: magento

I have been trying to get my Magento site to take some changes but it is still not refreshing the changes. I have disabled caching and flushed all of them on every single occasion I have also cleared my browser cache and it still does not take changes. I have gone as far to delete several files from the server that the theme relies on but it still functions like nothing was ever removed! What could be my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep editing those files. [I do not think](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2y8Sx4B2Sk) those files are the files you think they are.

You question is pretty short on details, but my first guess if your system is running with the compiler enabled, which means it's loading its class files from

```
includes/src
```

Googling around to learn about the compiler would be a good idea.

I'd try adding the following to the end of your `index.php` file

```
echo '<--';
print_r(get_included_files());
echo '-->';
```

This will list every file PHP used during the request.  Compare the **full paths** with the ones you're editing, and I bet you'll find a discrepancy.